# Using FPDI and FDP to generate slightly different pdf files

Tags: php, templates, fpdf, fpdi

i first import a pdf using fpdi to make a fpdf object, i then perform several changes on that pdf. I clone it to make a custom pdf just adding some texts. Then i output the two files to disk but just one is created and i got a fatal error for the second output :

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined method stdClass::closeFile() in **C:\Program Files\EasyPHP 3.0\www\oursin\oursin\public\scripts\FPDI\fpdi.php** on line **534**

pieces of my code:

```
$pdf = new FPDI('L','mm',array(291.6,456)); 
$fichier=$repertoireGrilles.'GR_IFR.pdf';   

$pdf->setSourceFile($fichier); 
// add a page 
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
$pdf->AddPage(); 
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx,0,0,0); 
.. 
... 
methods on $pdf 
.. 
.. 
.. 

$pdfCopie=clone $pdf; 

methods on $pdfCopie

$pdfCopie-> Output($repertoireGrilles.'grillesQuotidiennes/'.$date.'/Grille_'.$date.'_'.$ou.'_copie.pdf','F'); 
$pdf-> Output($repertoireGrilles.'grillesQuotidiennes/'.$date.'/Grille_'.$date.'_'.$ou.'.pdf','F');
```

Anybody to help me to tackle this issue that keeps my brain under high pressure for hours (days) :) ?

Comment: cloning an object isn't guaranteed to produce two totally independent objects. Most likely they're both still using the same FPDI. SO when you modify one, you're actually modifying both, and closing one closes both as well.

Comment: I think that in this case the objects are different because when i comment the ligne 534 in fpdi.php launching the closeFile method, two pdf files are generated and they are different and customized like i want. But the second one presents an error (xobject not found). i think i should prevent an action from taking place betweent the two output or maybe before but i didnt find wich one. Thanks answay for your comment

Comment: @MarcB This isn't quite the case. Adding text to one and not to the other will be preserved when you clone the FPDI. The issue comes from outputting them.

Comment: You can use forking, but it may be difficult depending on the environment you're in. Are you WAMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning, forking, copying, any of that is really dirty. You will have a very hard time with outputs if you take that route. Instead, consider this approach:

1. Make multiple AJAX calls to a single PHP file, pass a `pid` value to it so as to differentiate between them.
2. Go through the exact same document setup for FPDI. This is far more consistent than cloning, forking, copying, etc.
3. Check `pid` and do different things to different documents after all the setup is done.
4. Output the documents.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i;
    for( i=0; i<=1; i++ )
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:    'pdfpid.php',
            data:   {
                pid:    i,
                pdf:    'document.pdf'
            },
            type:   'post'
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, it's pretty simple. `pdfpid.php` is the name of the file that will generate and process the documents. In this case, I want the document with a `pid` of 0 to be my "original" and the one with a `pid` of 1 to be the "cloned" document.

```
//  Ensure that POST came in correctly
if( !array_key_exists('pid',$_POST) || !array_key_exists('pdf',$_POST) )
    exit();

//  Populate necessary variables from $_POST
$pid    = intval($_POST['pid']);
$src    = $_POST['pdf'];

//  Setup the PDF document
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->setSourceFile($src);
$templateID = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($templateID);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',24);

switch( $pid )
{
    default:
        break;
    case 0:
        //  "Parent" document
        $pdf->Text(10,10,"ORIGINAL");
        $filename = "original.pdf";
        break;
    case 1:
        //  "Child" document
        $pdf->Text(10,10,"CLONED");
        $filename = "cloned.pdf";
        break;
}

$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
```

I got both documents as an output, with the unique modifications between the "parent" and the "child" all in place.